# Xprinter open cash drawer

Tags: barcode-printing, tspl

I have some Xprinter XP-350 and XP-370 label printers - they have an RJ11 port just like the EPSON POS printers do. Although the usual EPSON [ESC p](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=195) command isn't working on these printers. They use the TSPL programming language so I have tried the `SET GPO` command from the [programming manual](https://www.pos-shop.ru/upload/iblock/e6d/e6dcd9090030c75de3ffd3435c1e2024.pdf). Specifically, I have tried: `SET GPO2 POS, 0, 20, 20, 100, PRINT`, but have had no success.

I also can't find a programming manual for this specific printer.